# Can I use Emmet to populate a script source?

Tags: html, emmet

I would like to be able to to use Emmet shorthand to populate the script source.

What I type script:src and press tab:

```
<script src=""></script> // Emmet produces this

<script src="script.js"></script>  // I want to produce this
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but you can create your custom snippets, most modern text editors allow that.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

> **Custom attributes**
>
> p[title="Hello world"]
>
> `<p title="Hello world"></p>`

So, `script[src="script.js"]` should be what you're looking to do.